# vba: filter column by array of criteria, all elements must be present

Tags: excel, vba

I've got a List (Worksheet) and every entry (row) has itself categorized in a cell (in a dedicated row) by comma separated integers.

Reading from a cell I am filtering the list accordingly in a "**OR**" connection:

e.g.

```
MyCriteria = Split(ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1").value, ",")

Dim i as Integer
For i=0 To UBound(MyCriteria)
  MyCriteria(i) = "*" & MyCriteria(i) & "*"
Next i

ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$E$200").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:=MyCriteria, Operator:=xlFilterValues
```

So if I'll enter `1,5,3` into cell A1, the column 5 (E) will be filtered and only rows are shown, in which at least one of the numbers 1, 5 or 3 are present. (this works)

**Question:**

How do I filter the same thing in a "**AND**" connection? Meaning all criteria-values must be present for the row to be shown (1,3 and 5 - in whatever order MUST be present).

Comment: Are you sure that your code filters as `OR` on all the criteria? I'm not sure you can add an array as `Criteria1:=` value. I suspect that its only applying your top criteria. You set the type of operator for the autofilter with the `Operator:=xlAnd` but this is already the default. You should try adding your filters in your loop so it hits all of them.

Comment: You'd have to put a formula in a new column that checks if all values are present and returns TRUE or FALSE, then you can filter this new column for TRUE values.

Comment: Actually I need to correct myself. According to this page: http://yoursumbuddy.com/autofilter-vba-operator-parameters/ you can use an array of criteria but it then defaults to `xlOr`. Try changing `xlFilterValues` to `xlAnd` and test.